# Django Bounded forms in Class based views - CreateView class

Tags: python, django, forms, get, django-class-based-views

How would I go about overriding the `GET` method in `CreateView` class based views to generate a **bounded form**, by which I mean it would have a preset value for some of its fields in the generated form (I need to instantiate the form with some defaults and not use the blank version of the form that CreateView uses by default).

I tried looking at https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/ but dont quite understand the flow of the `GET` method in this class.

**BaseCreateView**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**ProcessFormView**

> Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.
    """
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Where exactly do I override the get to instantiate my form, since CreateView uses modelFormFactory to generate the empty form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bound form: a bound form is one that's created from POST data and undergoes form validation.

To provide initial data for a new form, you override the [`get_initial`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_initial) method. Or you can just provide a class-level `initial` dictionary, if that data is static.

**Edit**

```
def get_initial(self):
    if request.GET.get('codereview-get'):
        initial = {'stream_name': 'TROI'}
    else:
        initial = {}
    return initial
```

Comment: I want to get something on the lines of UpdateView that creates a form with a model object fetched using the PK from kwargs, on a GET request. However I need to do this only if I pass a particular field in my GET request (not using the kwargs), which in turn I use to generate some data and have these forms instantiated with this data in its fields. In the case where the GET request is empty I would instantiate a blank form.

Comment: Yes, that is what you do in the `get_initial` method. You check the contents of `self.request.GET` and return either a dictionary with your defaults, or a blank dict.

Comment: So would I do something like this ? 


`def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET['codereview-get']:
            initial = {'stream_name': 'TROI'}
        return super(CreateEntryView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
`

Comment: No. You do it in `get_initial`, as I said.

Comment: Perfect that worked. I rewrote the get_initial - 
`def get_initial(self):
        if 'codereview-get' in self.request.GET:
            return {'stream_name':'TROI'}
        else:
            return {}`