# Django - Form (populate field with instance)

Tags: django, django-forms

```
obj = Contact.objects.get(id=1)
```

return is ->  124571  myName

from my database

```
 instanceForm = ContactFormDjango(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
```

ContactFormDjango was a form field with contact and name

my question is, how can i use my obj(Contact object id=1) to populate my form field as initial value when its load.

class

```
class ContactFormDjango(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = [
        'contact_no',
        'contact_provider',
        'contact_info'
    ]
```

Comment: I'm not following what is not working. Normally the data of the `obj` is loaded into the form fields of that instance as intial values.

Comment: yes and believe i should work that way, but i got an error. __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: you made a typo: it is `instance` (with two `n`s), not `instace`.

Comment: and if i change instance to initial=obj. 'Contact' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: can you share your `ContactFormDjango` class?

Answer (score 0):

In Class-Based Views you would override the [get_initial](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_initial) method to apply data to the initial forms.

A more detailed example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30241429/10796680).

Comment: yah, actually i like my initial value is from my obj(from database) and if it's static i can do it before my instanceForm  and add it

Comment: I am sorry but your sentences are incomprehensible as written. Please take the time to think about what you are typing before clicking send so that we can understand it.